# Excluding MYSQL query results with an INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I have two tables. The first is full of books each with a `book_id`. The second table is a `book_id` to `keyword_id` relationship table.

```
SELECT b.* FROM books_table b 
INNER JOIN keywords_table k 
ON b.book_id = k.book_id AND k.keyword_id NOT IN(1,2,3)
WHERE b.is_hardcover = 1 
GROUP BY b.book_id
```

### *Desired Outcome*

No books with the keyword_id 1, 2, or 3 attached to any of the books.

### *Actual Outcome*

Books can have the keywords 1, 2, or 3 so long as they have additional keyword_ids attached to them that are *not* in the exclusion list.

### *What I've tried*

The above query is the closest I have come to achieving it, but it fails in this one regard.

**How can I achieve the desired outcome and in the most optimized way?**

Comment: Desiring an outcome of "no books with ..." is confusing things for yourself and others.

Comment: Note that selecting columns other than the grouping column(s) and aggregate functions of the groups is not valid SQL.  It works for you because MySQL supports it as an extension.  That's fine if MySQL is the only environment you care about, but you should make that decision knowingly, rather than by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do so

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM books_table b 
INNER JOIN keywords_table k 
ON b.book_id = k.book_id
WHERE b.is_hardcover = 1 
GROUP BY b.book_id
HAVING SUM(k.keyword_id = 1) =0
AND SUM(k.keyword_id = 2) =0
AND SUM(k.keyword_id = 3) =0
```

Comment: Apologies for the delay in accepting your answer! It took me four months to finally get back to this project again after having to put it on hold and I didn't realize I left this hanging. This is the solution I went with. It works great and there's no second query on the potentially huge relationship table. Thanks a ton for your help!

Answer (score 3):

As you noted, this query will produce any book that has at least one keyword that isn't 1, 2 or 3, which isn't what you want. Instead, you'd want to explicitly exclude books with these keywords. A `join` isn't really the right took for the job here. Instead, you could use the `exists` operator:

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM   books_table b 
WHERE  b.is_hardcover = 1 AND
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   keywords_table k 
                   WHERE  b.book_id = k.book_id AND 
                          k.keyword_id IN (1,2,3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM books_table
WHERE is_hardcover = 1 AND
      book_id NOT IN (SELECT book_id
                      FROM keywords_table
                      GROUP BY book_id
                      HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN keyword_id IN (1,2,3) THEN 1 END) <> 0)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7421/1)

Comment: It looks like this will miss books that have no keywords assigned at all.

Comment: @JohnBollinger True. I made an edit to correct the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is a flavor of "anti join".  There are several ways to accomplish it; here's one:

```
SELECT b.* FROM books_table b 
LEFT JOIN keywords_table k 
  ON b.book_id = k.book_id AND k.keyword_id IN (1,2,3)
WHERE k.book_id IS NULL AND b.is_hardcover = 1
```

The left join matches up each row from the left table (`books_table`) with those rows of the right table that satisfy the condition `b.book_id = k.book_id AND k.keyword_id IN (1,2,3)`, *and* includes a single result row for each row of the left table that doesn't match any row of the right table.  The filter condition `k.book_id IS NULL` conflicts with the join condition, so it can be satisfied only by those rows arising from a left row not matching any right row.

Note that the assignment of conditions to the join predicate and the filter predicate is critical with an outer join such as this one.  Note also that there is no need for a `GROUP BY` clause in this case unless `books_table` may contain duplicate `book_id`s.

This approach is likely to perform better in practice than one based on a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause.  If performance is important, however, then you would be well advised to test the alternatives you are considering.